# button to choose language on my blog

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

Right now I have a perfectly working plugin ([Making wordpress multilingual](https://nl-be.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/developers/)) to put my blog in 2 languages.
In the sidebar on the right, I have 2 links right now that the plugin automatically provides, and they work on every page of my blog.
--> http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/

The thing is, I don't want the language option in the sidebar. I want to put it at the top of my blog. But the plugin only allows me to put it in the sidebar.

I tried copying the HTML on the homepage by using CTRL+SHIFT+I. And copying the whole block of HTML on the sidebar and pasting it in the HTML at the top of my blog. But then it doesn't work.

```
<ul>
<li class="lang-item lang-item-37 lang-item-nl lang-item-first"><a lang="nl-NL" hreflang="nl-NL" href="http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/">Nederlands</a></li>
<li class="lang-item lang-item-40 lang-item-en current-lang"><a lang="en-GB" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/en/">English</a></li>
```

Anyone have any idea how I can make this possible?

Comment: Please post more code as it is difficult to see where to place the currently available code.

Comment: Also, when you click a language,the language bar shows at the top of the page as expected.

Comment: mobile version doesn't let me comment so i'm commenting here, I don't get any code, that's the problem. I can only just click to add the widget and it ads the widget with the 2 languages to the sidecar. That code i gave in my question, I got that from CTRL+SHIFT+I. 

I gave the link of the plug-in , there you can download the whole html zip, i can't figure out in which document i can find the code i need to put at the top of my blog

Answer (score 0):

You can include a language switcher anywhere in your site by using the PHP template tag `pll_the_languages()`.
Read more information abaut The language switcher for this plugin in: https://polylang.pro/doc/the-language-switcher/